# Joining Sql tables to create new table with null being present

Tags: sql-server

I have one table with the product names and ID  numbers and a second with all the prices for these products from 2000 to 2015.

The result I'm trying to get is to have it display the product information and only the pricing information for 2015; but also still have it list all products even if they did not have a price for 2015 or a null row.

Any help in structuring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a `left join`.  Something like this:

```
select p.*, pp.price
from products p left join
     prices pp
     on p.productid = pp.productid and year(pp.date) = 2015;
```